# Elements rendering differently in Chrome/Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is really a head scratcher for me.

Certain elements on the following page are rendering differently in Chrome/Firefox and IE, specifically border radiuses and buttons.

It renders correctly in Chrome/Firefox but not IE.

Any ideas?

http://www.ansac.com/contact-us/soda-ash-request/

(the select list and email form footer is what is not rendering correctly in IE)

IE:
[image]

Chrome/Firefox:
[image]

Comment: First of all, provide code or at least a screenshot. Links die, so this question will render useless without any additional info. Secondly, site looks identical to me in IE9,10,11 and Chrome. [IE8 doesn't support border-radius](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) so that might be the problem. But I wouldn't make too big a deal out of it. Users with a browser that old shouldn't expect to get the best looking website.

Comment: It's IE 11, added some screenshots.

Comment: No, that's IE8. IE11 looks identical to your Chrome screenshot.

Comment: Argh, you know what?  I had that site added to compatibility view. That'll teach me to start coding before having coffee, thanks Bram.

Comment: No coffee, and working with Internet Explorer (or at least its older versions) is bound to go bad. ;-) Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Elements such as dropdown select are rendering differently depend of browser. 
What exaclly in border radius or buttons displaing wrong on IE?

Comment: IE 11 should render border radius without any problem. Try to add modernizer if any other way not working. [modernizer](https://code.google.com/p/clients-oriented-ftp/source/browse/trunk/includes/js/bootstrap/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js?r=203)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use border-radius and expect that it will render nicely in ie8. You can always check browser support for some css feature at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML contains the following directive in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

That probably switches IE into quirks mode. Try to replace it with `<!doctype html>`, that should switch IE to standards mode and all rounded corners should appear properly assuming it's IE11 as mentioned in comments earlier.

Additionally, you can enforce IE rendering mode by adding `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` as the first tag inside `<head>` (see [Internet explorer 9 will not recognize doctype sent by servlet from weblogic server and renders in document mode IE7 - extra characters before start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033551/internet-explorer-9-will-not-recognize-doctype-sent-by-servlet-from-weblogic-ser/29072822#29072822)).